# Erase every other number from $1, 2, 3, ... 2000$ until only one number left

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

One writes  $1, 2, 3, ... 2000$ on the blackboard.

We erase every other number from **left**, so after one iteration we are left with  $2, 4, ... 2000$

Then we erase every other number from **right**..

We keep repeating to erase from left and right one after another, eventually there is only one number left.

What would be that number?

I wrote a program, unless there is a bug, the answer should be 982. But is there a way to mathematically induce the results, and generalize to arbitrary number (not just 2000?)

Following the suggestion, it seems like for power of 2, the answers go like this

$N=2$, final number is 2

$N=4$, final number is 2

$N=8$, final number is 6

$N=16$, final number is 6

$N=32$, final number is 22

$N=64$, final number is 22

$N=128$, final number is 86

$N=256$, final number is 86

The answer will jump to 4 times previous answer minus 2, for every time we multiply $N$ by 4...

Comment: To start, I 'd work out what the final number was with lower caps (here, $2000$ is the cap).  See if you can spot a pattern.

Comment: as always, do the problem by hand with smaller sets. 1,2,3 to start. Then 1,2,3,4.  There is an odd/even aspect to this, and 2000 is 16 times 125, so you might get the first similar behavior for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16.

Comment: I'd start by looking at what happens if you write the numbers in base $2$.

Comment: See the relevant [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C3%2C3%2C1%2C1%2C3%2C3%2C9&sort=&language=english&go=Search) sequence for formula.

Comment: @momo thanks, but too bad I dont have access to the paper it refers to.. do you know where one can find it, or do you mind posting its ideas as the answer?

Comment: @VladZkov: *"too bad I don't have access to the paper it refers to"* ... The paper, "The Mathematics of Survival: From Antiquity to the Playground", is available on [JSTOR](https://jstor.org/stable/3647800), which allows free online access to a limited number of articles per month from the vast journal archive. (They significantly boosted the limit due to the COVID-19 pandemic, at least through the end of June.)

Comment: @Blue thanks! quite a fun  read!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a step, at least, toward a solution.

Let $S(N)$ denote the "surviving" number as a function of $N$. Now after the first pass from left to right, only the even numbers from $2$ up to $2\lfloor N/2\rfloor$ remain. Thus $S(N)$ satisfies the recursion

$$S(N)=2(\lfloor N/2\rfloor+1-S(\lfloor N/2\rfloor))$$

with $S(1)=1$ (i.e., once only one person, that person survives). Let's see first how this works for a power of $2$:

$$\begin{align}
S(32)&=2(17-S(16))\\
&=34-4(9-S(8))\\
&=-2+8(5-S(4))\\
&=38-16(3-S(2))\\
&=-10+32(2-S(1))\\
&=54-32\\
&=22
\end{align}$$

Now let's look at $N=2000$:

$$\begin{align}
S(2000)&=2(1001-S(1000))\\
&=2002-4(501-S(500))\\
&=-2+8(251-S(250))\\
&=2006-16(126-S(125))\\
&=-10+32(63-S(62))\\
&=2006-64(32-S(31))\\
&=-42+128(16-S(15))\\
&=2006-256(8-S(7))\\
&=-42+512(4-S(3))\\
&=2006-1024(2-S(1))\\
&=2006-1024\\
&=982
\end{align}$$

as the OP found. Whether the recursive formula can be simplified to an explicit closed formula I'll leave to someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete solution, using the excellent recurrence of Barry Cipra.

Consider the $k$-bit-long binary representation of $N = b_1 b_2 b_3 \dots b_k$ where $b_1$ is the most significant bit.

For convenience define $B_j = b_1 b_2 \dots b_j = \lfloor N / 2^{k-j}\rfloor$, i.e. the number formed by the most significant $j$ bits.  Note that $B_k = N$ and $B_1 = b_1 = 1$.

Next we "unwind" the recurrence a bit:

$$
\begin{align}
S(N) = S(B_k) &= 2(B_{k-1} + 1 - S(B_{k-1}))\\
&=2(B_{k-1} + 1) - 2 [ 2(B_{k-2} + 1 - S(B_{k-2}) ] \\
&=2(B_{k-1} + 1) - 4(B_{k-2} + 1) + 4 S(B_{k-2})
\end{align}
$$

A nice thing now happens: if I may abuse notation a bit and mix up numbers with their binary representations (in red),

$$2B_{k-1} - 4B_{k-2} = \color{red}{b_1 b_2 \dots b_{k-2} b_{k-1} 0 - b_1 b_2 \dots b_{k-2} 0 0 = b_{k-1}0} = 2b_{k-1}$$

where the binary representations (in red) have some appended $0$s at the end to represent multiplication by $2$ or $4$.  So now we can unwind faster:

$$
\begin{align}
S(B_k) &= 2(b_{k-1} -1) + 4S(B_{k-2}) \\
&=2(b_{k-1} -1) + 4[2(b_{k-3} - 1) + 4 S(B_{k-4})]\\
&=2(b_{k-1} -1) + 8(b_{k-3} - 1) + 2^4 S(B_{k-4})\\
&=2(b_{k-1} -1) + 8(b_{k-3} - 1) + 32(b_{k-5}-1) + \dots
\end{align}
$$

Note that the subscript $j$ of the remaining $S(B_j)$ term decreases by $2$ for each unwinding step.  So what happens at the end of all the unwinding can be case-analyzed:

**For odd $k$:** the last remaining term will be $S(B_1) = S(b_1) = S(b_1) = b_1 = 1$:

$$S(B_k) = \sum_{j = 1, 3, 5...} 2^j (b_{k-j} - 1) + 2^{k-1} S(B_1) = \sum_{j = 1, 3, 5...} 2^j (b_{k-j} - 1) + 2^{k-1} b_1$$

Interpretation: Based on the way I number the bits, $2^j b_{k-j}$ is the $b_{k-j}$ bit evaluated at its correct place-position.  So the formula is equivalent to this recipe:

> **Recipe:** Take the most significant bit's place-value (blue), and consider the $2$nd, $4$th, $6$th, etc least significant bits (red), i.e. the bits for place-values $2^1, 2^3, 2^5,$ etc.  If a bit is $0$, then subtract its place-value.

E.g. $2000 = 11111010000 = \color{blue}{1}\color{red}{1}1\color{red}{1}1\color{red}{0}1\color{red}{0}0\color{red}{0}0 \implies S(2000) = 1024 - 2 - 8 - 32 = 982$

E.g. $64 = 1000000 = \color{blue}{1}\color{red}{0}0\color{red}{0}0\color{red}{0}0 \implies S(64) = 64 - 2 - 8 - 32 = 22$

**For even $k$:** the last remaining term will be $S(B_2)$.  Luckily, $B_2 \in \{2, 3\}$ and in both cases $S(B_2) = S(2) = S(3) = 2$.

$$S(B_k) = \sum_{j = 1, 3, 5...} 2^j (b_{k-j} - 1) + 2^{k-2} S(B_2) = \sum_{j = 1, 3, 5...} 2^j (b_{k-j} - 1) + 2^{k-1} b_1$$

So surprisingly, **the same recipe works!**  The only clarification is that since the most significant bit is also an even-numbered least-significant bit (because $k$ is even), it must not be included in the subtraction.

E.g. $32 = 100000 = \color{blue}{1}0\color{red}{0}0\color{red}{0}0 \implies S(32) = 32 - 2 - 8 = 22$

**Further remarks:**

- It is curious that only half the bits matter.  E.g. the recipe immediately shows $S(8) = S(1000_2) = S(13) = S(1101_2)$.
- Barry's recurrence is already $\log(N)$ time, so my recipe is not faster.  However, it does give an explicit summation.
- The explicit summation, especially in the form of the recipe, allows easy proofs of the OP's observation that $S(2^k)$ values come in pairs, and $S(2^{k+2}) = 4S(2^k) - 2$.

Comment: Thanks that's great answer!